# apache tomcat output with colors in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, logging, tomcat

I usually use tomcat plugin in eclipse and run it from eclipse. 
Now I want to use it from terminal. but the problem is I dont get the output in colors. Atleast the errors should be displayed in red .

Any idea how to achieve this ?

EDIT: If no such tool exists, can anyone guide me to create one. I am interested to create one such tool.

Comment: the short answer is -- forget about it :) Eclipse parses the log output, and highlights it based on that parsing. To achieve the same on the terminal, you'd either need: (1) special terminal driver, (2) filter program that does the same parsing and outputs ASCII sequences that set color, or (3) - modification of the log framework to encrust log output with ASCII sequences, when it's dumped to a terminal.

Comment: so seriously, the output is just a plain text and eclipse takes pain in changing colors :o

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way actually, first you need to make apache tomcat log using log4j instead of the default logger. 
Then you can actually customize the output for log4j. You are going to have to read a bit on logging for tomcat, and about log4j, you can have console output configured and then you can have what ever colors you need in them since they are customizable.

Some links that will help you .

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

http://marc.info/?l=log4j-user&m=120574713010072

Answer (score 0):

Try [this class written by Dan Dyer](http://blog.uncommons.org/2006/04/09/colour-coded-console-logging-with-log4j/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ccze](http://freecode.com/projects/ccze) , but still not perfect work with less or tail, works well with static log

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `grep`'s line buffering mode.

1. Using tail

   ```
   tail -f fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
2. Using less

   ```
   less +F fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
3. Using watch & tail to highlight new lines

   ```
   watch -d tail fileName
   ```

   - For linux based systems.